# Prevent Terminal Scrollback In Curses (Python)?

Tags: python, macos, curses, iterm2

Setup: iTerm2 in Mac OS X with a python 2.7 application using curses. Leaving it alone works fine; it uses a timer to update information and rewrite the screen and two pads. If I accidentally "scroll up" with the mousewheel or mousepad, I see the individual "frames" written by iterations in the program's while-loop. Also, this causes some kind of memory or CPU lag such that it takes a VERY long time to get back to the bottom and view the actual application again.

If at all possible, I'd like to avoid this. Any thoughts?